# Wierd error when trying to run app with AdMob

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[GADWebViewDelegate webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADWebViewDelegate.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What does it means? what do I need to do in order to fix that?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add AVAudioPlayer and MessageUI frameworks. That's about it.

Answer (score 2):

FYI - I had to add the AudioToolbox framework to get this to compile.

Answer (score 1):

From where ever you have got the library that you are using, its only compiled to be used on the device.. (architecture armv7), where as you are trying to test it on the simulator (architecture i386) thus the error. So if you want to test it on the simulator, get a version of the library which is compiled for i386.

You can also combine both the libraries using lipo command and use it on any architecture..

hoping this helps.. :)

Comment: well, the solution was that I just needed to add AVAudioPlayer and MessageUI frameworks. thats it. But thanks anyway for your response.

Comment: :P, hmm learned another thing today.. one should focus on the class that's missing, rather than just the error . thanks man.